# Running Eslint on Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, eslint

I need to run Eslint on Java. The only solution I thought about is to "browserify" the node-js module, and try to run it on Rhino. 
Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: Maybe you can  take a look at this: http://nodyn.io/